# Has keytab got a lifetime?

Tags: linux, kerberos, keytab

I've have a keytab that is scheduled to run daily(just once) to renew it's ticket. However, I wanted to find out whether keytab  itself has any lifetime? I assume it doesn't as the cron job has been configured to execute daily which i think will create a new ticket instead of renewing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Brought from mit kerberos: "A keytab (short for “key table”) stores long-term keys for one or more principals." The keytab file will store your key which allows you to automate your usage of the kerberos principals without any "human interaction". As you know the tickets are only valid between a somewhat short amount, typically between 12 and 24 hours, however the keytab is valid as long as you find it valid. By this i mean that if any third entity get hold of the keytab it loses all it's purpose.

Comment: is it safe to assume that keytab will be valid as long as I want it to be (until i change the password?)

Comment: Yes. As long as you do not change your password which would require you to generate a new key entry/keytab and as long as you save it in a safe environment(Assume no third party has access to your keytab, either remote or locally).